# Fill input field with javascript ipinfo response

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I would like to fill input field with javascript ipinfo API response.
I am ready to fill a PRE but not an INPUT. I need to send it by a form in order to save this information.

Please see it here http://jsfiddle.net/ak2txped/2/

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    $("#ip").html(response.ip);
    $("#code").html(response.country);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + 
    response.region);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
  }, "jsonp");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="details"></pre>
<form id="details" action="/action_page.php" method="post">
  Details: <input type="text" name="fname" value="pre"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot repeat ids.  You've repeated the `details` id.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page

Comment: you are right, I have solved, but I can't fill this API response into input form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give input id

`<input type="details" name="details" value="pre"  id="fname">`

then set the value using JQuery from the response.

`$("#fname").val(response.org);`

working link

http://jsfiddle.net/ak2txped/5/

Comment: @RaulTaboraz  you are most welcome. If you need any help please message me.